# How to copy only updated rows from Google Sheets to Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-2010, google-sheets-api, export-to-excel

Currently, I'm connecting Jotform to Google sheets where information with the submissions are uploaded. We primarily use excel for the bulk of our operations and would like to connect the submissions uploaded from google sheets to excel. I can use import data from web which excel offers but it more so just copies the entire table even if you delete some rows on excel.

I want to do something similar to what zapier offers where the connection is not just a copy of the entire table and it only uploads new rows uploaded to google sheets onto excel and refreshes frequently.

Is there a way I can do this? My best bet is to use Google sheets API's? But i'm not sure where to get started.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's better to share what you have done already. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: Since you currently get submissions in Google Sheets, one option would be to start doing the "bulk of operations" right there. For reporting, take a look at [pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900) and spreadsheet functions such as [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) and [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Answer (score 1):

What are "new" submissions? Excel need to know that.

You can directly import the data from jotform to Excel, no need to do it via google sheets.

Yes, even then all submissions are downloaded, that will always be the case. But not all need to be displayed. You can choose in and with Power Query what shall remain and loaded to Excel.
If you don't use a date for what you consider new, you have to store all old data in Excel as well, so Excel can see whether a submission is already downloaded before or not. You could load all data to the Data Model, where it uses very little space.

You need to learn PowerQuery for this. It is very worth it, because with little learning you can do a lot of fantastic things to your submissions and other data.